# I Created a table and Made a column as Foreign Key to two other tables in EF Code First Approach

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Here is my sample code

```
class Sample
{
public int Id{ get;set; }
public int AssociatedSiteId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("AssociatedSiteId")]
        public virtual SiteA Site { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("AssociatedSiteId")]
        public virtual SiteB SiteB { get; set; }
}

I m Inserting the data as
using (var dbcontext = new sampleEntities)
{
var sample = new Sample();
sample.Id=1;
sample.AssociateId = siteInfo.SiteId; // This Id from SiteA Table
dbcontext.Sample.Add(sample);
dbcontext.SaveChanges();
}
```

where I try to Insert Data into Sample, I m getting the error as:

The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint.

I m new to EF Can any one please help me?

Comment: Can you post the insertion code?

Comment: var sample = new Sample();

Sample.UserName = userName;
                        sample.IsSuccess = true;
                        sample.IsActive = true;
                        sample.NoofAttempts = 1;
                        sample.LoginTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
                        sample.SessionTimeStamp = DateTime.UtcNow;
                        sample.IsConsultSite = false;
                        sample.AssociatedSiteId = siteInfo.SiteId;
dbContext.Sample.Add(sample);
                        dbContext.SaveChanges();

Comment: Edit the code into your question, it's unreadable as a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming you need some guidance :)

I have a question: Why Site and SiteB are using the same foreign key variable? Aren't them different entities? (SiteA and SiteB)

If you have

```
Sample.SiteA => MySiteA
Sample.SiteB => MySiteB

they cannot use the same foreignh key. Even if they are the same type, that key is used to locate the foreign entity and you would be overwriting one with the another... Check your code with mine.
```

Try the following:

```
class Sample
{
  public int Id{ get;set; }

  public int AssociatedSiteAId { get; set; } // Optional but sometimes useful if you don't use [ForegnKey("...")]

  [ForeignKey("AssociatedSiteAId")]
  public virtual SiteA Site { get; set; }


  public int AssociatedSiteBId { get; set; }  // Optional but sometimes useful if you don't use [ForegnKey("...")]

  [ForeignKey("AssociatedSiteBId")]
  public virtual SiteB SiteB { get; set; }
}
```

On your code,

```
using (db = new DbContext())
{
  var site_a = db.SitesA.Find(123); // 1 should be the key of site a
  var site_b = db.SitesB.Find(456); // 2 should be the key of site b

  Sample sample = new Sample()
  {
     SiteA = site_a,
     SiteB = site_b
  };

  db.Samples.Add(sample);
  db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: hi Jorge, thanks for the reply. but my scenario is I need to capture the siteIds of both SiteA and SiteB and store for reference

Comment: The example I posted does just that. I think the problem is you are sharing one foreign key among to entities. Let's say SiteA has key 123, and SiteB has key 456, which value will AssociatedSiteId store? 123 or 456?

Comment: Just to clarify: AssociatedSiteId is an int, it can store one and only one int. It will store the key (siteId) of one of your relationships. Where will the other key go?

Comment: ok Jorge, so what you mean to say is that, it is not possible to Implement only one Id for Both in EF,  Am I correct? or Please Correct me If m wrong.

Comment: Right. Maybe we should work on your model, I don't have your requirement clear. Do you need to store a list of sites for a "Sample"?